# How can I make Packer properly execute the 'echo -e' command?

Tags: escaping, echo, packer

In my Packer script I use an `echo -e` command to allow me to append newlines to a file, but I noticed that Packer is not handling this as I would expect.

Here are the relevant parts of my Packer source file:

```
provisioner "shell" {
  environment_vars = [
    "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive",
  ]
  inline = [
    "echo -e \"new\nline\" | tee -a /home/ubuntu/new_file.txt",
  ]
}
```

Normally if I were to execute `echo -e "new\nline"` in a shell it would output

```
$ echo -e "new\nline"
new
line
```

but during the build process Packer instead prints out

```
-e
new
line
```

How can I make Packer properly execute the 'echo -e' command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of Google-fu I was able to find that someone else had raised [this issue on the Packer GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/7703) which lead me to the relevant parts of the documentation.

The [shell provisioner documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/docs/provisioners/shell) actually explains why this is happening:

> inline_shebang (string) - The shebang value to use when running commands specified by inline. By default, this is `/bin/sh -e`

I tried launching `/bin/sh` in a terminal to make sure that `echo -e` provides the expected output and I found the reason for my problem:

```
sh-3.2$ echo -e "new\nline"
-e new
line
```

#### Solution #1

Remove the `-e` flag from the echo command since `/bin/sh` does not need it to interpret newlines

```
provisioner "shell" {
  environment_vars = [
    "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive",
  ]
  inline = [
    "echo \"new\nline\" | tee -a /home/ubuntu/new_file.txt",
  ]
}
```

#### Solution #2

Use the `inline_shebang` parameter to tell Packer to use `/bin/bash` which will allow the `echo -e` command to execute as expected

```
provisioner "shell" {
  environment_vars = [
    "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive",
  ]
  inline_shebang = "/bin/bash -e"
  inline = [
    "echo -e \"new\nline\" | tee -a /home/ubuntu/new_file.txt",
  ]
}
```